# Merge to replace only nan values

Tags: pandas, merge, missing-data

i need to replace only nan values in col A from col B

```
A
  key  lvalue group
   a     1.0     a
   c     NaN     a
   e     3.0     a
   a     1.0     b
   c     NaN     b
   e     3.0     b

B
  key  lvalue
   a       2.0
   c       2.0
   e       5.0
```

Expected output:

```
  key  lvalue group
   a     1.0     a
   c     2.0     a
   e     3.0     a
   a     1.0     b
   c     2.0     b
   e     3.0     b
```

i have tried few thing like:

```
A = np.where(A['lvalue'].isna(), B, A)
A.fillna(B)
A.combine_first(B)
pd.merge_ordered(A, B, left_by='key')
A.loc[A['lvalue'].isnull(),'lvalue'] = B['lvalue']
```

But no luck. Please help me achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not as elegant as I thought it would be, but you could merge `A` and `B` together, then use the added column to fill `lvalue` and finally drop that column again:

```
C = A.merge(B, on='key', suffixes=('', '_y'), how='left')
C['lvalue'] = C['lvalue'].fillna(C['lvalue_y'])
C.drop(columns='lvalue_y')

#   key lvalue  group
# 0 a   1.0     a
# 1 c   2.0     a
# 2 e   3.0     a
# 3 a   1.0     b
# 4 c   2.0     b
# 5 e   3.0     b
```